# Why we can consider inductor as a current source when the current loop gain infinite?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, circuit-design, power-electronics, loop-gain

I am reading about current-mode control from [this site](https://www.powersystemsdesign.com/articles/current-mode-control/37/9768). 
Please look at the excerpt below and especially the boldfaced part.

**Question**:

**Why we can consider inductor as a current source when the current loop gain infinite?**

From feedback theory, if the loop gain is infinite then we have \$i_{L}*R_{i} = v_{c}\$. 
However, vc is not a constant voltage so how the inductor current constant?
The output capacitor will be charged and discharged alternatively so there should be some non-zero vc.

> Infinite-Gain Models
>
> Probably the most universal approach used by industry appeared in the
>   Unitrode Handbook and application notes. **If the gain around the
>   inductor current is assumed to be infinite, we can treat the inductor
>   as a current source.** This follows the logic of the current following
>   the reference by the action of the comparator. Figure 4 shows the
>   resulting model. The controlled current source feeds the RC load, and
>   the resulting model is first order.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Vc is a constant - it sets the level i.e. it is the demand. You need to be clearer in your question that Ri isn't R x i and that iL is i x L unless of course I've fallen foul of your confusing terminology.

Comment: I have just edited  the formula. I was a bit lazy with Latex. BTW, why vc is constant? The output capacitor always charges and discharges in one period so this means that vc should be a non-zero and not a constant too. Is there something wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: In actual operation in a current mode supply, Vc is as @anhnha says the demand.  So to a first order in steady-state it's constant, but the whole point is really that you're making a voltage-controlled current source with the current loop.  So the voltage loop programs a current and the two-pole output filter you would have in voltage mode becomes a single pole.